# Instruments Allocation tool stopping mid run

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments

I set up Instruments to load the Allocation module.  I pick out my phone, then select my app as the target.  I hit the 'record' button and my app starts up and Instruments starts recording fine.

However when I enter a certain section of my code, Instruments will disconnect.  The monitor and timer just stop and the record button grays out.  On the phone my app continues to run merrily.  Sometimes Instruments gives the error message 'Failed to start instruments daemon' but it is not 100%.

This section of the code doesn't do anything terribly different from the sections that have already run.  It is entering a new area so a lot of new memory is allocated and some new threads are spawned.  I do believe I am leaking some of the memory allocated (when i leave the section) and I am hoping to use Instruments to help me track which allocation.  Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: it may help if you post some of the relevant code